# Rendering on gpu causes streaks in render

Tags: gpu

When rendering on gpu there are prominent streaks in the render preview and to a lesser extent the final image. This problem started recently but not after any particular update and the problem persists even after resetting blender preferences to defaults. The problem is also not isolated to a single project.
Any ideas?

I am using an amd r9 390.

GPU:
[image]

CPU:
[image]